# Cyclic Property Change Listeners

Tags: java, propertychangelistener, propertychangesupport

I have a cyclic property change listener set up. I have 2 objects of class A. I have made one object listen to changes of the other and vice versa. Here's the code:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CyclicPCLTest {

    public static class A implements PropertyChangeListener{
       private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
       private String date;

        public A(String date) {
            this.date = date;
            propertyChangeSupport=new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public String getDate() {
           return date;
       }

       public void setDate(String date) {
           String oldDate=this.date;
           this.date = date;
           propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "date", oldDate, this.date));
       }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
            propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            setDate ((String) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> as= Arrays.asList(new A[]{new A("01/02/2011"), new A("01/02/2011")});
        as.get(0).addPropertyChangeListener(as.get(1));
        as.get(1).addPropertyChangeListener(as.get(0));

        as.get(0).setDate("02/02/2011");
        System.out.println("date of the other A "+as.get(1).getDate());

        as.get(1).setDate("03/02/2011");
        System.out.println("date of the other A "+as.get(0).getDate());
    }
}
```

The code works and this is the output:

```
date of the other A 02/02/2011
date of the other A 03/02/2011
```

I am wondering how it does? Shouldn't it give me a stackoverflow error? When the first A is updated it notifies the second A, the second A then gets updated and notifies the first A. This should go on for ever.

Comment: did u debug and test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `firePropertyChange` will only fire the event if `oldValue` is **not equal** to `newValue`

After 2 recursive runs, when the code reaches

```
propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "date", oldDate, this.date));
```

the `oldDate` and `this.date` essentially become same (that is `oldDate.equals(this.date) == true` ) and it doesn't propagate the event to the listeners

Check the documentation of `firePropertyChange` method

> Fire an existing PropertyChangeEvent to any registered listeners. **No
>   event** is fired if the given event's old and new values are **equal** and
>   non-null.

Comment: Ah.. how did I miss that! Thanks